# Install libspatialindex on windows in Rtree

Tags: python, r-tree

I am trying to install libspatialindex on windows running python3.5 and cant figure out how to do it. I downloaded Rtree from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rtree) . This page also points me to the libspatialindex page [here](http://libspatialindex.github.io/). I download the windows file but dont know how to install it as it is not a .whl file.

I have searched a lot for how to install it and havent come up with anything yet. If someone can help, that will be very useful! thanks